# Bash command to cut output after x number of lines

Tags: linux, bash, gnu

I'm looking for a bash command, which I can use to limit the number of lines of a file or another command output. E.g.

```
ls -thor | limit 10
```

would limit the output of the ls command to 10 lines (in the example, the command "limit" is naturally a imaginary command, whose equivalent I'm looking for). Is there such command, or a related solution?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Use [**head**](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/head-invocation.html):

```
ls -l | head -n 15
```

10 lines is the default. Read the [**head**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/head.1.html) man page for more options.

(older versions of **head** also support usage without the explicit `-n` as in `head -15`)

Comment: beat me to it :)

Comment: Thx. I should have figured it out, it's obvious when you know that there is a "tail" command.. :)

Comment: Syntax -integer is (at least in GNU version of head/tail discouraged - you should be using -n 15)

Comment: I didn't know that. Old habits die hard. I'll have to try to learn that.

Comment: The current GNU Coreutils version `head` accepts `head -15` (but only if it's the first argument). The document describes this option as obsolete.